# PHP :fetch value from MYSQL table and sum it

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table who has 2 field Product and Price.

Now if product have value apple multipletime  with diff price like,

```
Product and Price.
apple         5
apple         10
apple        15
bananaa    20
```

Now i want to fetch apple value only 1 time  and sum of all apple price altogether.how can i fetch value in this concept.and apple is not ONLY FIXED value it could be any product from table like banana, grapes etc....

Comment: [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Really?  SELECT Product, SUM(Price) as totalPrice FROM table WHERE Product = '$product' GROUP BY Product.  Invest some time in learning Sql basics.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Product,SUM(Price) from fruits group by Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has to start somewhere...

```
Select Product, Sum(Price) as TotalApple
From TableName
Where Product='apple'
Group by Product
```

Hope I didn't just do your homework for you :)